# Explicit value of a Bessel integral

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Given the integral :

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xK_{\mu}(x(a+b))}{K_{\mu}(xa)}J_0(cx)dx$

where $K_{\mu}(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $\mu$ and $J_0(.)$ is the Bessel function of order $0$. $a,b,c$ and $\mu$ are positive real constants.

Is it possible to explicitly calculate the value of this integral? I guess the first step to this would be to proving it's convergence and then moving forward. But I am not sure where should I start with this. Any sort of help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: When $\mu=1/2$ it can be done.  Because $K_{1/2}$ is elementary.  But the case $a=b=c=\mu=1$ seems to be unknown to Maple.

Answer (score 1):

For convergence ... it seems
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{xK_{\mu}(x(a+b))}{K_{\mu}(xa)}J_0(cx) =
\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^\mu
$$
exists.  And as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
\frac{xK_{\mu}(x(a+b))}{K_{\mu}(xa)}J_0(cx)\sim
\left( {\frac {\sqrt {a}\sin \left( cx \right) }{\sqrt {a+b}\sqrt {
\pi}\sqrt {c}}}+{\frac {\sqrt {a}\cos \left( cx \right) }{\sqrt {a+b}
\sqrt {\pi}\sqrt {c}}} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
so I guess that it converges (but only conditionally) on that end.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain how you obtained these results. At this point it is a bit difficult for me to follow.